# Recent Badges link to All Badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, hyperlinks

Recently, the list of recent badge awardees has been moved from the front page to the side of the badges page. At the bottom of the list there is still a link to "all badges" which also links to the badges page. Perhaps this feature should be awarded the Recursion Badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in the next deployment (meta `rev.1894` and network `rev.1331`)